# php 5.4 String offset cast occurred

Tags: php

on the following lines I get the error 'String offset cast occured'

```
$code[$value['dictionaryAlias']] = $value['dictionaryText'][$codeLang];

$code[$value['dictionaryAlias']] = $value['dictionaryText'][$langDefault];
```

Actually,  the code access a table.  It works in previous version but not in 5.4

I am a newbie and I am in charge in converting the code. What changes should I make to make it work.
I read that it is probably because the variable is a string instead of an array. What can I do then?

Comment: What var_dump($value); prints?

Comment: This is a bug in your software that never has been detected. Note that possible offsets in a string are only integers

Comment: You first treat `$value` as an array and then you treat it as a multidimensional array.  For example, if `$value['dictionaryText'][$codeLang]` is a thing.. then the "value" of `$value['dictionaryAlias']` would be "Array()", which you are trying to use as the index for `$code`.

Comment: "As of PHP 5.4 string offsets have to either be integers or integer-like strings, otherwise a warning will be thrown. Previously an offset like "foo" was silently cast to 0."

Comment: thank you. I'll try to change the code.  Actually, the code is not written by me. I just trying to convert it. $code is an array. As you said, the $value is treated as an array and a multidimensional array. It works in previous verion of Php. I dont know why

Comment: Just to be clear, it's unlikely to work. It probably behaves slightly incorrectly without producing an error.

Answer (score 16):

This means that `$value['dictionaryText']` is a string, and either `$codeLang` or `$langDefault` is not an integer. The indexing operator works on strings, but only accepts integer indices: when it receives something else, it tries to convert it to an integer, most often resulting in the value 0, and returns the character at that index.

This is a new warning that they introduced in 5.4 because it was a frequent mistake and a frequent cause of headaches.