# function broke after updating PHP

Tags: php, warnings

I have a little problem with a function which doesn't seem to fully work in new php version and I receive

> Notice: String offset cast occurred in D:\xampp\htdocs\decode\bencoded.php on line 266
>   Notice: String offset cast occurred in D:\xampp\htdocs\decode\bencoded.php on line 270

Here is my function:

```
function bdecode($s, &$pos=0) {
  if($pos>=strlen($s)) {
    return null;
  }
  switch($s[$pos]){
  case 'd':
    $pos++;
    $retval=array();
    while ($s[$pos]!='e'){
      $key=bdecode($s, $pos);
      $val=bdecode($s, $pos);
      if ($key===null || $val===null)
        break;
      $retval[$key]=$val;
    }
    $retval["isDct"]=true;
    $pos++;
    return $retval;

  case 'l':
    $pos++;
    $retval=array();
    while ($s[$pos]!='e'){
      $val=bdecode($s, $pos);
      if ($val===null)
        break;
      $retval[]=$val;
    }
    $pos++;
    return $retval;

  case 'i':
    $pos++;
    $digits=strpos($s, 'e', $pos)-$pos;
    // Proger_XP: changed (int) -> (float) to avoid trimming of values exceeding
    //            signed int's max value (2147483647).
    $val=(float)substr($s, $pos, $digits);
    $pos+=$digits+1;
    return $val;

//  case "0": case "1": case "2": case "3": case "4":
//  case "5": case "6": case "7": case "8": case "9":
  default:
    $digits=strpos($s, ':', $pos)-$pos;
    if ($digits<0 || $digits >20)
      return null;
    $len=(float)substr($s, $pos, $digits);
    $pos+=$digits+1;
    $str=substr($s, $pos, $len);
    $pos+=$len;
    //echo "pos: $pos str: [$str] len: $len digits: $digits\n";
    return (string)$str;
  }
  return null;
}
```

i understand that i get a warning in the new php, but i have no idea how to fix it.

line 266 (before case 'd'):      switch($s[$pos]){

line 270 (after case '1'):        while ($s[$pos]!='e'){

Comment: ok my bad . i modifyed the title. i take any suggestions

Comment: And there's little reason PHP3/4 code wouldn't run on PHP5. It's not an entirely different language, mind you; and the sample code (posting it off-site is a no-go anyway) is pretty low-level and hardly doing anything fancy. You're better off just figuring out what it was supposed to do, and rewrite it else.

Comment: What are the lines 266 and 270 ?

Comment: all i want to do is get infohash from a torrent wich i do but i also get a bunch of errors. i would also be happy if i loose the errors because i have what i need otherwise.

Comment: this post will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16697988/php-5-4-string-offset-cast-occurred

Comment: Did you check at error line var_dump( Your variable ) ? Type of you offset at those lines?

Comment: yes .. the thing is that i get the infohash. All i want is loose the errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think the simplest solution to solve this should be to disable the notices using the follwing code:

```
// Report all errors except E_NOTICE
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
```

You may want to do this if you are sure that the code always returns the correct result and the notice doesn't matter.

**Why is the notice shown?**

As far as i can see, the notice is shown because you try to access the strings offset not by an integer but by an float value.

The key lines of your code are these:

```
$len=(float)substr($s, $pos, $digits);
$pos+=$digits+1;
$str=substr($s, $pos, $len);
$pos+=$len;
```

`$len` is casted to float and added to `$pos`. The result is that `$pos` is converted to float after doing this. No problem. But you will get the notice if you use `$pos` later to access the offset of your string because it is not an integer any more:

```
//line 266 (before case 'd'): 
switch($s[$pos]){

//line 270 (after case '1'): 
while ($s[$pos]!='e'){
```

maybe you want to solve it by convert `$pos` to int explecit like this:

```
//line 266 (before case 'd'): 
switch($s[(int)$pos]){

//line 270 (after case '1'): 
while ($s[(int)$pos]!='e'){
```

The result of your function should be the same and the notice should been gone.