# in PHP correct solution for String offset cast occurred

Tags: php, string

on the following functions, I get the error

> 'String offset cast occured'

```
protected function setBitAtPosition($pos) {
    list($char, $byte) = $this->position2CharAndByte($pos);
    // Error Notice :  String offset cast occurred in ....
    $this->bitField[$char] = $this->bitField[$char] | $byte;
}

protected function getBitAtPosition($pos) {
    list($char, $byte) = $this->position2CharAndByte($pos);
    // Error Notice :  String offset cast occurred in ....
    return ($this->bitField[$char] & $byte) === $byte;
}


var_dump($this->position2CharAndByte($pos));
array(2) {
  [0] =>
  double(9552303)
  [1] =>
  string(1) "Ç"
}
```

As of PHP 5.4 string offsets have to either be integers or integer-like strings, otherwise a warning will be thrown.

Is the correct solution is to cast to integer like this

`$this->bitField[(int)$char] = $this->bitField[(int)$char] | $byte;`

`return ($this->bitField[(int)$char] & $byte) === $byte;`

Comment: Please read comments and answer of this link:--- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16697988/php-5-4-string-offset-cast-occurred

Comment: Also can you show output of `var_dump($this->position2CharAndByte($pos));`

Comment: I update with the output of `var_dump(...)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution is to cast `$char` to an `int`; although a `double` has the same value, PHP explicitly expects ints since 5.4. The fix is to have `position2CharAndByte` return an `int` instead of a `double`, casting it in the caller of `position2CharAndByte` requires unnecessary code duplication. (*cough*[fixed](https://github.com/deceze/BloomFilter/commit/76efba6c0014f8643a04c6c72471f5b8e67d0cd5)*cough*).